# WooCommerce Layered Nav Widget

Tags: widgets, navigation, page-attributes

Has anyone used the "WooCommerce Layered Nav" widget.
I wonder if the attributes could be visible on the single product page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solve this problem:

```
<?php if (is_singular() ) : ?>

    <?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute) : ?>
        <h3><?php echo $woocommerce->attribute_label( $attribute['name'] ); ?></h3>
        <ul>
            <li><?php $values = woocommerce_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], 'names' );
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values ); ?></li>
        </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the attributes of a product by putting the following code in a template file:

```
global $product;
$product->list_attributes();
```

Comment: I enter this code in the single-product.php page but nothing happens, I'm doing something wrong can you help me?

Comment: This I found on the official site [woocommerce](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/layered-navigation-widget/)  "The layered navigation widget will only appear on product archives".  I hope there is a way to solve this